# Accessing Rally SOAP service from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, rally

Is it possible to access Rally's SOAP services from Silverlight? I am able to access the service from a .NET 2.0 proxy in a desktop application, but not via a WCF client proxy in Silverlight. I get the following familiar exception,

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 
>   An error occurred while
>   trying to make a request to URI .... This could be due to attempting
>   to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper
>   cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP
>   services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish
>   a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP
>   headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal
>   types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details.

I believe the problem is caused by trying to make a cross domain request from Silverlight, which requires a cross domain policy file installed on the server. If this is the case, why does the desktop application not require such a policy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Silverlight expert, but this looks like a cross-domain scripting/security sandbox that Silverlight imposes to make sure that Silverlight clients don't make requests to sites other than the server/host from which they were downloaded, unless the Silverlight client is specifically granted that right by the service provider/devloper. In the error message above:

"You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent."

I think the "owner of the service" means the owner of the Silverlight host, rather than the "external" webservice (in this case, Rally).

Desktop and/or console apps wouldn't have this same sandbox restriction. You would probably encounter the same issue trying to access another vendor's webservices via a Silverlight client.

You might find this Silverlight-specific thread:

[Cross Domain Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848608/cross-domain-policy)

Helpful for the specifics of how to setup and configure a Silverlight cross-domain policy file on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight was built with security in mind.  That means cross site scripting from the Silverlight application is turned off by default and must be enabled on a case by case basis.  A .NET desktop application, on the other hand, generally has far greater security permissions and can call whatever web services, COM objects, and native APIs it pleases.

The way you work around this issue in Silverlight is to create a service on your server.  The Silverlight client code calls your server side service which in turn calls a third party web service.  The server side service can bet .NET, java, whatever.  Web servers can generally call whatever they like -- problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I considered this approach, but managed to resolve it by using elevated trust in Silverlight 5.

Comment: Yes, that's the other way to solve it: blast a bunch of permissions at your app. :)  If you don't need to run inside a browser, it might be easier to do an elevated trust out of browser app.  The difference is the in-browser elevated trust stuff looks like you MUST sign your app for everything to work.  Whichever is easier for your depends on your situation and organization.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this myself by using the extended permission features available in Silverlight 5. Since the xap is deployed on an internal internet, this solution was acceptable.