# WCF Cross domain service creation

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I've REST based WCF service which is host on IIS 7.5. It is working fine, but when try to access from PHP application. It's returning blank response.
Actually the plan is, to make it available to open world. Just like yahoo weather service.

This service performs CRUD operations.

I've tried below options but no use
[Cross Domain Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848608/cross-domain-policy),
[Cross-domain calling a WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703517/cross-domain-calling-a-wcf-service),
[Cross domain ajax and WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480351/cross-domain-ajax-and-wcf)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Enabling [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) and looking at the resulting logs might give you some clues as to where and why it fails.

Comment: Does your application expect xml or json? Do you need to [enable jsonp support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2011/04/19/supporting-jsonp-callbacks-in-wcf-data-services.aspx)? and [see also](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/514598/Understanding-OData-v-and-WCF-Data-Services-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WCF based REST services, we have this configuration (snippet) in web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <!-- a REST help page is auto-generated, and viewable at http://<host_name>:<port>/service/help -->
      <!-- 'crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled' means that it supports JSONP calls (a 'callback' is supplied in the url) when the response is formatted as json. -->
      <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```